# Nested list comprehension - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Probably there is quite an easy solution for this, but I just can't seem to find it.

I have multiple names which I'm trying to join together:

```
dir_name = ['bseg', 'ekpo']
sys_name = ['a3p065', 'a3p100']
paths = [os.path.join(a, b) for a in (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), name) for name in sys_name) for b in dir_name]
```

`paths` gives me:

```
['C:path\\a3p065\\bseg', 'C:path\\a3p065\\ekpo', 'C:path\\a3p100\\bseg', 'C:path\\a3p100\\ekpo']
```

However I need such a format:

```
[['C:path\\a3p065\\bseg', 'C:path\\a3p065\\ekpo'], ['C:path\\a3p100\\bseg', 'C:path\\a3p100\\ekpo']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually have a nested list comprehension; you have a single comprehension with two iterators.

Compare

```
[x for y in z for x in y]  # One comprehension, two iterators
```

with

```
[[x for x in y] for y in z]  # Two comprehensions, each with a single iterator
```

---

For your case, you want something modeled on the latter:

```
dir_name = ['bseg', 'ekpo']
sys_name = ['a3p065', 'a3p100']


paths = [[os.path.join(os.getcwd(), s, d) for d in dir_name] for s in sys_name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? (I'm using `"."` for the root path, but feel free to use `os.getcwd()`.)

```
import os

dir_names = ["bseg", "ekpo"]
sys_names = ["a3p065", "a3p100"]
localized_sys_names = [os.path.join(".", name) for name in sys_names]
paths = [
    [os.path.join(sys_name, dir_name) for sys_name in sys_names]
    for dir_name in dir_names
]

print(paths)
```

Output:

```
[['a3p065/bseg', 'a3p100/bseg'], ['a3p065/ekpo', 'a3p100/ekpo']]
```

Answer (score 0):

A nesting of lists requires nested list comprehensions. One to iterate over the `dir_names`, and another for the `sys_names`. Try this:

```py
dir_name = ['bseg', 'ekpo']
sys_name = ['a3p065', 'a3p100']
paths = [[os.path.join(a, b) for a in (os.path.join(os.getcwd(), name) for name in sys_name)] for b in dir_name]
```